# Unit testing $http resolve in controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, karma-jasmine, angular-ui-router

I need help with my controller test. I have a `resolve` using ui-router. In my test, I need to figure out how to handle the `resolve`'s `exampleData`.

**config.js**

```
angular.module('myModule')
  .config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider',

    function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

      $stateProvider
        .state('site', {
          abstract: true,
          resolve: {
            exampleData: function(ExampleService) {
              // ExampleService.get() makes an $http call
              return ExampleService.get();
            }
          },
          // etc
        })
        .state('example', {
          parent: 'site',
          url:'/example',
          controller: 'ExampleCtrl as example',
          templateProvider: function($templateCache) {
            return $templateCache.get('views/example.html');
          }
        });

    }]);
```

**example-controller.js**

```
angular.module('myModule')
  .controller('ExampleCtrl', ['exampleData',
     function(exampleData) {

       var self = this;
       self.exampleData = exampleData;

       // self.exampleData should output something like
       // [
       //   {id: 1, title:'something'},
       //   {id: 2, title:'something'},
       //   {id: 3, title:'something'}
       // ]

  }]);
```

**example-controller.test.js**

```
   describe('Controller: ExampleCtrl', function() {
      beforeEach(module('myModule'));

      var ctrl;

      beforeEach(inject(function($controller) {
        ctrl = $controller('ExampleCtrl');
      }));

      describe('initialization', function() {
        beforeEach(function() {});

        it('should exist', function() {
          expect(!!ctrl).toBe(true);
        });

        it('should ...', function() {
          // do something
        });
      });
```

When I run the tests, I get the following error:

```
Unknown provider: exampleDataProvider <- exampleData <- ExampleCtrl
```

My question is: what do I do in order to test the `resolve` in my `ExampleCtrl`? The `ExampleService.get()` is a service which makes an `$http` call and returns and array of objects.

Answer (score 0):

Testing `resolve` method of `$state` is not what you want to do. It's part of angular and it has appropriate tests.

What you should focus in your tests is your app's logic. There should be a section for testing `ExampleService` (`get` returns a promise, `get` issues an http request, etc.) and testing for `ExampleCtrl` which should make sure that controller processes data properly. But resolving dependencies is not what should be tested.

What, imo, should be the solution in this case is substitute `exampleData` resolving for the sake of test.

```
 var exampleData = [
      {id: 1, title:'something'},
      {id: 2, title:'something'},
      {id: 3, title:'something'}
    ];
  module('myModule', function($provide) {
    $provide.value('exampleData', exampleData);
  });

  beforeEach(inject(function($state) {
    ctrl = $controller('ExampleCtrl');
  }));
```

Comment: I'm getting a `Unexpected request: GET /api/example` when I run the tests. The `ExampleService.get()` performs that request using `$resource`.

Comment: Which test? The code you posted in OP doesn't trigger `ExampleService` in controller. So it can't be the case. You must have more than one test suite and `ExampleService` is not mocked there

Answer (score 0):

You need to manually instantiate the example data.I had the same problem so i use this method to resolve it. will work fine for you also.

```
 describe('Controller: ExampleCtrl', function() {
      beforeEach(module('myModule'));

      var ctrl,exampleData;

      beforeEach(inject(function($controller,ExampleService) {
        exampleData = ExampleService.get();
        ctrl = $controller('ExampleCtrl',{exampleData});
      }));

      describe('initialization', function() {
        beforeEach(function() {});

        it('should exist', function() {
          expect(!!ctrl).toBe(true);
        });

        it('should ...', function() {
          // do something
        });
      });
```